# Should we always use "between" with "and"? What about using "between" with "or"?

Tags: prepositions

I know I can say

> I have to choose between A and B.

I am wondering if I can say something like:

> I have to quickly decide between doing it now **or** tomorrow.

And generally speaking, is it correct to use between and or together?

Comment: Your second example makes good sense, is colloquial English and is grammatically correct (other than a split infinitive, which is a rule borrowed from Latin and frequently ignored).

Comment: It is correct, though I prefer to use "either" instead of "between" in this kind of situation.

Comment: You can't do with time what you can do with a group of things.

Comment: @holydragon: If you use **either** you'd have to change the verb phrase. "decide either doing it now or tomorrow" or "decide doing it either now or tomorrow" would be ungrammatical. You have to say "decide **to do** it either now or tomorrow".